# how to play two mp4 videos through gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: video, gstreamer

I would like to create a gstreamer pipeline to play two mp4 videos back to back.
is it possible to play using gst-launch?
can I use multifilesrc for this purpose ?

Please show me path to play two videos back to back.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a way to do this using a single gst-launch command. The video decoder sends an end of stream event after the first video ends when you use multifilesrc.

If you are dead set on using gst-launch, you can wrap two gst-launch commands in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
file1=$1
file2=$2

gst-launch filesrc location="$file1" ! decodebin2 ! autovideosink
gst-launch filesrc location="$file2" ! decodebin2 ! autovideosink
```

Another way to do this is to write a simple GStreamer application in C to create a pipeline for the first video, play it, create a new pipeline for the second application, and play that.

See the GStreamer application developers guide: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/

The section [Hello World](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-helloworld.html#section-helloworld) contains a functional example pipeline which I think would make a good starting point for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please Point me in which section that sample code is described.

Comment: @arr Modified the answer. See the [Hello World](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-helloworld.html#section-helloworld) chapter.