# How to play next source file after receiving EOS

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, concatenation

I am trying video playback using gstreamer.
I want to play video files one after another without stopping.
I tried the following method, but the second file did not play.

$gst-launch-1.0 conact name=c ! autovideosink filesrc location="video0.mp4" ! decodebin ! c.  filesrc location="video1.mp4" ! decodebin ! c.

Why doesn't the second file play correctly?

Comment: You have typo: it should be "concat" instead of "conact". Other than that, it works fine on my side on Ubuntu with gstreamer version 1.16.1

Comment: I'm sorry.This is a typo in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** It turns out that this is not possible for video files. See: [how to play two mp4 videos through gstreamer pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446332/how-to-play-two-mp4-videos-through-gstreamer-pipeline)

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for but I would use `multifilesrc` in this case.

You can define a format for filename such as `video%d.mp4`. Multifilesrc will use this format in `sprintf()`, and enumarate `video0.mp4`, `video1.mp4`, ...

```
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location=video%d.mp4 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.I tried it, but the window closed without playing the second file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tested with `.h264` files when I wrote this answer. It turns out that for video files `decodebin` sends `eos` signal, so this is multifilesrc is not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446332/how-to-play-two-mp4-videos-through-gstreamer-pipeline